# Android load graphic

Tags: java, android, memory, graphic

I have a problem. I have a large graphic for my main menu/start screen. This causes an out of memory exception on some older devices. It is a PNG file with the resoluton 1920*1080 and I use the ImageFormat RGB565. Do you have any ideas how I can reduce the used ram?

Comment: Reduce the size of the image.  Why on earth do you need an image of that size for a small Android device?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned you may scale down the image but if for some reason you don't want to or you can't do that you may want to check that link:

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Also you may add

```
largeHeap=true
```

To increase memory a little bit but it will work only on new devices, Android 2.x does not support that

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for:

```
BitmapFactory.Options.inSampleSize
```

> If this is set to true, then the resulting bitmap will allocate its
>   pixels such that they can be purged if the system needs to reclaim
>   memory. In that instance, when the pixels need to be accessed again
>   (e.g. the bitmap is drawn, getPixels() is called), they will be
>   automatically re-decoded. For the re-decode to happen, the bitmap must
>   have access to the encoded data, either by sharing a reference to the
>   input or by making a copy of it. This distinction is controlled by
>   inInputShareable. If this is true, then the bitmap may keep a shallow
>   reference to the input. If this is false, then the bitmap will
>   explicitly make a copy of the input data, and keep that. Even if
>   sharing is allowed, the implementation may still decide to make a deep
>   copy of the input data.

Source:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize

So basically you can adjust the `inSampleSize` based on the screen resolution and available RAM so that you always have an adequate version of the bitmap for a given device. This will prevent `OutOfMemoryError` errors from occuring.

Here's an example of how to make use of it:

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and width
        final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
        final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

        // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will guarantee
        // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
        // requested height and width.
        inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

Source: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html
There's also some more info under that link so I'd recommend that you check it out.